# how to make thread-safe row matrix in java

Tags: java, multithreading, matrix, thread-safety

I have a problem: I have a structure that represent a matrix of int. I have to do some operation on single row of this matrix and that operations have to be thread safe. 
I thought of lock the entire matrix but I want to lock only the single line.
How can I do that??? thx

Comment: Do you have a separate object for each line? (arrays are objects, so you *can* synchronize on them)

Comment: No I have this: int matrix[][] = new int[n][m].

Comment: is it [row][column] or [column][row]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java does not actually support multidimensional arrays natively. A 2D array is simply an array of arrays.

Therefore, you could synchronize on a single row:

```
synchronized(matrix[row_index]) {
    // do stuff with matrix[row_index] here
}
```

This is assuming no other code reassigns `matrix[row]` (the array itself, not the elements); if it can, then you need a temporary variable to avoid the race condition where another thread might reassign it in the middle of your `synchronized` block:

```
int[] the_row = matrix[row_index];
synchronized(the_row) {
    // do stuff with the_row here (NOT matrix[row_index])
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a separate array of lock objects:

```
// a field in your Matrix class
Object[] row_locks;

// initialized like this (probably in your constructor, or whenever the matrix is resized)
for(int row_index = 0; row_index < number_of_rows; row_index++)
    row_locks[row_index] = new Object();

// and used like this:
synchronized(row_locks[row_index]) {
    // do stuff with the row_index'th row here
}
```

Comment: Depending on performance concerns, a `ReentrantReadWriteLock` per row would reduce the synchronization cost in the case that the matrix is both read by and written to by multiple threads.

Answer (score -2):

You have to keep an array to store the row number that is currently busy. Each time you will access a row you will have to call a function that populates this array in order to prevent others to access the same row. If you finish working on the a specific row you will delete the row number from the array to make it accessible for others again.

Comment: Downvoted for a horrible synchronization idea that won't actually work properly.

Comment: This scares me slightly. I sure hope it's an [`AtomicIntegerArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.html) that you're talking about.

Comment: @BoristheSpider of course it is, otherwise there is no point to keep such an array.

Comment: @immibis well it worked better than synchronized when I needed something like that